# UWP display name depending on environment

Tags: uwp

We have a UWP Application distributed to the Microsoft Windows Store.
For testing use, we also have a test and acceptance version in de appcenter.
When a user wants to have a, for ex, a acception version and released version side by side, it is not possible.
When installing the appxbundle file it says the app is already installed (probably because it has the same name). 
Is it possible to have multiple display names depending on the environment, for ex, when you have app "MyApp", you can also have a "MyApp -Test"  and "MyApp - Acc" app.

thx

Comment: You could try to change the Package name of your project in the visual studio and run it to see if it can build successfully.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. Thanks very much

Comment: Glad you solved it and I have converted my comment to answer.

Comment: Hi, can the following method help? Can it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you could change the package name to make a project copy. Double-click the appx.manifest file => Click Packaging Tab => Modify the package name to a different one. Then run your project and it won't conflict with others.